# My code is showing error in taking input of string in for loop "java.util.InputMismatchException"?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, input

If I am taking the Same input outside for loop it is showing no error, And only String input is showing error other input like double and int are successfully taken in for loop as well as outside.

```
import java.util.*;

class jignasu
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc  = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a;
    String name;
    double paid;
    String str = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(str);
    double permonth;
    a=sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        name=sc.nextLine();// ====> is giving  java.util.InputMismatchException
        paid=sc.nextDouble();
        permonth=sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(name+"                    "+paid+"                    "+permonth);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: What input you are giving in that line

Comment: Any name like say "Laptop"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a;
        String name;
        double paid;
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(str);
        double permonth;
        a = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            name = sc.nextLine();// ====> is giving  java.util.InputMismatchException
            paid = sc.nextDouble();
            permonth = sc.nextDouble();
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(name + "                    " + paid + "                    " + permonth);
        }
    }
```

Your **sc.nextInt()** will not read the newline character in your input. So that your **sc.nextLine()** return that newline character. To get rid of this you can either call **sc.nextLine()** after your **sc.nextInt()** call. Or else you can use **sc.nextLine()** in place of **sc.nextInt()** and parse the result as Integer then.

Comment: What was the problem, can you explain?

Comment: @SubramanianMariappan Yes nextInt() after nextLine() giving error but why nextDouble after nextLine not giving error ?

Comment: @Tarun You can go through this for deeper understanding. https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/232053/nextline-after-nextint-or-nextdouble-gives-trouble

Comment: @Tarun Calling nextInt() after nextLine() is not a problem but calling nextLine() after nextInt() is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do some debugging and you will see the exception coming from the next line

paid=sc.nextDouble();

and you will see the first line in the for loop ignored 
do this by printing some messages before each time you ask for input

to solve it replace

name=sc.nextLine();

by

name = sc.next();